# Override Internal Dependency in Node 14

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, overriding, npm-vulnerabilities

I was fixing vulnerabilities in a project for which I needed to override some internal dependencies.
I used `Override:{}` to override those dependencies, but just now, I came to know that I could not use Node 16, and I need to fix these issues by staying on Node 14.
So How can I override these dependencies in Node 14 where there is no option to override using `Override:{}.`

Comment: What library do you use which relies on Node 14? Maybe there's an alternative..

Comment: @sandrooco Whole project is built on Node 14 and I'm bound to the Node 14, not allowed to upgrade to Node 16.

Comment: Well that sucks. Node 14 isn't even in long term support anymore...